# Passing a variable to a mongo modifier

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to update an array element in a document, but i want to be able to control which element(s) dynamically, so this works:

```
var doc = Collection.findOne({...});  
Collection.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {"field.1.subfield": 10}});
```

But I want to be able to pass a javascript variable to the 1 of the "field.1.subfield"

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick, parse an object to $set.

```
var n = {};
n['field.'+i+'.subfield'] = 10;
Collection.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:n});
```

Ping us back if you have issues with it.